# How to select an item for dropdown menu with mechanize in python?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, mechanize

I am REALLY confused. I'm basically trying to fill out a form on a website with mechanize for python. I got everything to work except the dropdown menu. What do I use to select it and what do I put for the value? I don't know if I'm supposed to put the name of the selection or the numerical value of it. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Code snippet:

```
try:
        br.open("http://www.website.com/")
        try:
            br.select_form(nr=0)
            br['number'] = "mynumber"
            br['from'] = "herpderp@gmail.com"
            br['subject'] = "Yellow"
            br['carrier'] = "203"
            br['message'] = "Hello, World!"
            response = br.submit()
        except:
            pass
    except:
        print "Couldn't connect!"
        quit
```

I'm having trouble with the carrier, which is a dropdown menu.

Comment: Please give a concrete example. Show the code you tried and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: You'll probably get better answer if you rewrite your question title to be a summary of your problem instead of what appears to be a list of tags (the list of tag is here just for that). And there is no need to say "Please Help!", since if you're asking a question, you are obviously asking for help.

Comment: I changed the title to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [mechanize documentation examples](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html), you need to access attributes of the `form` object, not the `browser` object. Also, for the select control, you need to set the value to a list:

```
br.open("http://www.website.com/")
br.select_form(nr=0)
form = br.form
form['number'] = "mynumber"
form['from'] = "herpderp@gmail.com"
form['subject'] = "Yellow"
form['carrier'] = ["203"]
form['message'] = "Hello, World!"
response = br.submit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're going to reply, because I asked this yesterday, but for "carrier", would I set the value to the name of what's in the dropdown list or the value? ex: Name: Foo    Value: 129

Comment: Could you post the html of the form in question, so I can test it properly and reply?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for reviving a long-dead post, but this was the still best answer I could find on google and it doesn't work. After more time than I care to admit, I figured it out. infrared is right about the form object, but not about the rest, and his code doesn't work. Here's some code that works for me (though I'm sure a more elegant solution exists):

```
# Select the form
br.open("http://www.website.com/")
br.select_form(nr=0) # you might need to change the 0 depending on the website

# find the carrier drop down menu
control = br.form.find_control("carrier")    

# loop through items to find the match
for item in control.items:
  if item.name == "203":

    # it matches, so select it
    item.selected = True

    # now fill out the rest of the form and submit
    br.form['number'] = "mynumber"
    br.form['from'] = "herpderp@gmail.com"
    br.form['subject'] = "Yellow"
    br.form['message'] = "Hello, World!"
    response = br.submit()

    # exit the loop
    break
```

Comment: You might be able to do control.disabled=False control.value = ["203"] instead of looping. Let me know

Comment: first I think the selected property should read "selected" instead of True, second, having br.form["carrier"] = "203" should be sufficient.